# GUI extension - Namespace Issue on adding column in a List View

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, sdl-tridion

I am trying to add new column to Dashboard View in SDL Web 8.5 and following the instructions provided by SDL [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-22B407FA-BAD1-4081-B8C7-F4D9E3F77D74.xml&docid=GUID-F2914FC9-3384-4566-8E3A-7A09D6757173&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-F2914FC9-3384-4566-8E3A-7A09D6757173)

Event handler is working as expected and is adding custom attribute ext:ExpirationDate the value to response when GetList is invoked.

I am able to see the header for the table but there is no content. Refer to screenshot below:
[image]

Tridion configuration:
[image]

Issue seems to be with the namespace 'http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/R5/Extension' which is not recognized; although it has been configured in GUI extension configuration.

I was able to resolve the issue by directly adding adding namespace to \web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Xml\ListDefinitions\ListItems.xml

[image]

Am I missing any step? Any help would be appreciated. We do not want to update any out of the box configuration.

Comment: I don't think we need to include that namespace anymore. Here is a working example. You can try that -
https://github.com/justsayantan/PublishedEnvironemntDataExtender/blob/master/PublishedEnvironmentDataExtender/Configuration/DataExtender.config

Comment: '@paras' '@glens' - I am facing the similar issue in 9.1. Were you able to fix it with the hotfix? do we need hotfix for 9.1 as well?

Comment: Yes. I was able to resolve the issue with the hotfix. But had to update out-of-the-box ListView.js  at TRIDION_HOME/web/webUI/Core/Control/List for filtering to work.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend reaching out to SDL Support to request access to hotfix CME_8.5.0.9078 (http://csei.sdl.com/hotfixes/#/hotfixes/c)

Comment: Thanks Glen. Is there a way to filter the results based on item type? Requirement is add column only for Structure groups.